# How can you tell if your device has been whitelisted?

Tags: chromecast

I got the email back from Google and they said they have, but having trouble getting it to show up under devices using some of the example code they provide, but now wondering if maybe I gave them the wrong serial or something and it really hasn't been white-listed.

Comment: Ugh, I have the same problem.  Why there isnt an actual manager to be able to add/edit devices and urls is beyond me.  Cant a company who makes more revenue than a small country afford someone to put together an actual interface to this stuff?  What I did was resubmit my deviceid last night, I guess now I wait for someone do dig it up from that excel worksheet somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always email them with the developer ID (Should be in the email), app ID, and your serial # to have them check. One thing I learned, though (when experiencing the same thing), was that I forgot to configure my chromecast with the "send this serial # to Google when communicating about updates" flag. If that isn't checked, then your Chromecast can't be notified that it is allowed to communicate with your app id. Also note that the Chromecast Android app had a bug (don't know if today's update fixed it) where setting that flag wouldn't stick, so I had to do it through the desktop app and then reboot the Chromecast and wait a few hours for the next time it pinged Google.

Comment: I checked that last night but didn't realize it might take a few hours to pick it up, so that may be the problem. I don't think I have a developer ID though, where did you get that?

Comment: It was in the email I got back from Google after they confirmed my whitelisting... it said to use it in all communications.

Comment: I gave it another shot tonight and I think it was just that it takes time for Google to ping your Chromecast, my same test scripts that weren't working last night work tonight.

Comment: @jlmcdonald can U tell me what the url should contain for whitelist the device... Having confusion... Could u please tell me ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates" setting enabled using one of the ChromeCast setup apps for your OS or Android. And reboot your ChromeCast device after enabling that setting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open Chrome and enter http://[ip.to.chrome.cast]:9222 in the browser address field. If your cromecast device is whitelisted the page will open.